Syntax error on NEXT statment in nested for loops HP 28s
I am trying to convert a simple program for looking though the first 1000 numbers and counting how many primes are there. though right now I can't even get nested for loops working. The error is on the NEXT statement, it says there is a Syntax Error.
Here is my code
≪ 1000 →n 2 →c 0 →q
0 →v
3 n FOR j
3 → j
≪
2 q FOR i
2 → i

i SQ

NEXT
≫
2 STEP
≫

I don't know what i'm expecting from this program, i'm just trying to get nested for loops with the same ranges and incrementing behaviors as what i would use in my program. though for this I would expect it to put i squared (as in the value of the counter i to the power of 2) in the stack repeatedly.

If this is still of interest ...
This is the FOR example from the HP28C reference manual
1 3 FOR x x SQ NEXT

(just type it in and hit [ENTER], it pushes the values 1 4 9 on the stack)
So FOR expects the start value on the stack in level 2 and the end value in level 1, then binds it to the given variable name as a local variable. In the example the name is 'x' and it is available until the NEXT keyword.
Therefore nested FOR loops would look like this:
1 3 FOR y 1 3 FOR x x y + NEXT NEXT

This pushes the numbers 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6 on the stack.
With formatting and explanation:
1 3           // start end for outer loop
FOR y         // outer loop with variable y
  1 3         // start end for inner loop
  FOR x       // inner loop with variable x
    x y +     // compute sum of x and y
  NEXT        // next iteration of inner loop (increments x)
NEXT          // next iteration of outer loop (increments y)

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more advice, or if you figured this out by yourself, or maybe you have discarded the HP28 by now?
